# How to use Smallrye Mutiny to call a void method which throws checked exceptions

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny

When using Smallrye Mutiny to handle exceptions, the imperative code becomes more fluent. I can even call methods that throw checked exceptions by using `Unchecked.supplier()` to handle them:

```
LifecycleConfiguration lifecycleConfiguration = Uni.createFrom().item(Unchecked.supplier(() -> minioClient.getBucketLifecycle(GetBucketLifecycleArgs.builder().bucket(bucketName).build())))
        .onFailure().transform(e -> new CommonSystemErrorException("Failed to get MinIO bucket life cycle configuration", e))
        .await().indefinitely();
```

However, I cannot apply the same approach to methods that throw checked exceptions and return `void`. For instance, consider the following method:

```
public void setBucketLifecycle(SetBucketLifecycleArgs args) throws ErrorResponseException, InsufficientDataException, InternalException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidResponseException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, ServerException, XmlParserException {
    try {
        this.asyncClient.setBucketLifecycle(args).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException var3) {
        throw new RuntimeException(var3);
    } catch (ExecutionException var4) {
        this.asyncClient.throwEncapsulatedException(var4);
    }

}
```

If I write the code below, the IDE raises alerts in two places:

```
//                     vvvv IDE alerts: Cannot resolve method 'item(Supplier<T>)'
Uni.createFrom().<Void>item(Unchecked.supplier(() -> minioClient.setBucketLifecycle(SetBucketLifecycleArgs.builder().config(lifecycleConfiguration).bucket(bucketName).build())))
//                                                   ^^^^ IDE alerts: Bad return type in lambda expression: void cannot be converted to T
        .onFailure().transform(e -> new CommonSystemErrorException("Failed to set MinIO bucket life cycle configuration", e))
        .await().indefinitely();
```

Is it possible that I can call methods that throw checked exceptions and return `void` using Smallrye Mutiny, without additionally using try and catch?

Answer (score 1):

To make it happen, just try this:

```
Uni.createFrom().<Void>item(Unchecked.supplier(() -> {
            minioClient.setBucketLifecycle(SetBucketLifecycleArgs.builder().config(lifecycleConfiguration).bucket(bucketName).build());
            return null;
        }))
        .onFailure().transform(e -> new CommonSystemErrorException("Failed to set MinIO bucket life cycle configuration", e))
        .await().indefinitely();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to call it like this:

```
public Uni<Void> foo() {
   return Uni.createFrom().voidItem().invoke(() -> yourVoidMethod());
}
```

Or if you want to catch any exceptions from your void method then you can call it like this:

```
public Uni<Void> foo() {
   return Uni.createFrom().voidItem().invoke(Unchecked.consumer(x -> yourVoidMethod()));
}
```